# Log4Net param from Properties without programming

Tags: log4net

I tried to setup my Log4Net dynamical. But some properties in my Appenders wont work.

I.e. in my Program.cs

```
GlobalContext.Properties["hostname"] = Environment.MachineName;
GlobalContext.Properties["serviceName"] = ServiceProperties.ServiceName;
GlobalContext.Properties["smtpHost"] = LoggingProperties.SMTPServer;
GlobalContext.Properties["maximumFileSize"] = LoggingProperties.MaximumFileSize;
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
log.Debug("Logger configured.");
log.Fatal("I am a Mail"); // Mail Logging Test
```

And the part of my app.config

```
<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
    <param name="smtpHost" value="%property{smtpHost}" />
    <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
      <threshold value="FATAL"/>
    </evaluator>
    ....
</appender>
```

In my SmtpAppender, it literally says "%property{smtpHost}" als String, same with every other property.

Can I use the properties in my config without programmatically set everything or do I have to code the whole appenders?

Regards

Comment: Yes, you can use properties in code and reference them in config. I wonder if the problem is that you set them before configuring log4net?

Comment: It is the very first thing I do in the program. I set the properties in the GlobalContext and call the Configuration

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Try configuring and **then** setting the properties - they are evaluated during logging, not set during configuration.

Comment: I added the code of my ConfigureLogger() Method. I don't use it before the Properties Settings are set.

Comment: Oh, after that. I give it a try

Comment: Nope, changed it and set the Properties AFTER I configured it, not working.

Comment: Thinking about it, I don't think you _can_ set appender "properties" by using properties. Had a dig through the log4net source and they're really only used during actual logging events. So it looks like you might have to create the appender programatically after all. Sorry if I wasted your time.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your time. I Programm the logger tomorrow, not as comfortable as an xml but i will make my own library of it for the future